# Google maps infowindow not showing on click in Symfony2 with VichGeographicalBundle

Tags: php, symfony, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, symfony-2.1

I have successfully set up [VichGeographicalBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichGeographicalBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) to display a bunch of places in a Google Map. Everything works ok, except the infowindows that do not show on click.

`$this->setShowInfoWindowsForMarkers(true);` is set but does not seem to work.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT:**

```
class allShopsMap extends Map
{
    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of LocationMap.
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // configure your map in the constructor 
        // by setting the options

        $this->setShowZoomControl(true);
        $this->setZoom(13);
        $this->setAutoZoom(false);
        $this->setContainerId('map_canvas');
        $this->setWidth(980);
        $this->setHeight(360);
        $this->setShowInfoWindowsForMarkers(true);
        $this->setCenter(23.232323,23.232323);
        $this->setShowMapTypeControl(true);

        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT st
                       FROM acme\ShopBundle\Entity\Shop sh 
                       WHERE sh.published = 1 ");
        $shops = $query->getResult();

        foreach ($shops as $shop) {
            $this->addMarker(new MapMarker($shop->getLatitude(), $shop->getLongitude(),$icon='images/map_marker.png'));
        }
    }
}
```

Called from twig template:

```
{{ vichgeo_map('allShops') }}
```

config.yml

```
vich_geographical:
    db_driver: orm 
    query_service: vich_geographical.query_service.default
    map_renderer: vich_geographical.map_renderer.google
    templating:
        engine: twig
        info_window: msgrShopBundle:Map:infoWindow.html.twig

services:
    msgr.map.allShops:
        class: msgr\ShopBundle\Map\allShopsMap  
        tags:
           -  { name: vichgeo.map, alias: allShops }
        arguments: 
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

HTML Code generated by `{{ vichgeo_map('allShops') }}` : http://pastebin.com/jqvzG67N

Comment: A live link showing the error might help us help you. Also the code where the error occurs

Comment: David, there is no error displayed at all. I simply click on the marker and nothing is displayed.

Comment: The markers are all displayed successfully on the map and javascripts are included in the <head>. The infoWindow drives me insane, as I have traced through the code of VichGeo and saw that nothing suspicious is here. Also, no js errors in firebug. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class allShopsMap extends Map
{
    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of LocationMap.
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $infoWindowBuilder)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // configure your map in the constructor 
        // by setting the options

        $this->setShowZoomControl(true);
        $this->setZoom(13);
        $this->setAutoZoom(false);
        $this->setContainerId('map_canvas');
        $this->setWidth(980);
        $this->setHeight(360);
        $this->setShowInfoWindowsForMarkers(true);
        $this->setCenter(23.232323,23.232323);
        $this->setShowMapTypeControl(true);

        $query = $em->createQuery("SELECT st
                       FROM acme\ShopBundle\Entity\Shop sh 
                       WHERE sh.published = 1 ");
        $shops = $query->getResult();

        foreach ($shops as $shop) {
            $marker = new MapMarker($shop->getLatitude(), $shop->getLongitude(),$icon='images/map_marker.png');
            $marker->setInfoWindow($infoWindowBuilder->build($marker)); 
            $this->addMarker($marker);
        }
    }
}
```

infoWindowBuilder is `vich_geographical.info_window_builder` service that is available in the container.

And modify your config:

```
services:
    msgr.map.allShops:
        class: msgr\ShopBundle\Map\allShopsMap  
        tags:
           -  { name: vichgeo.map, alias: allShops }
        arguments: 
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" 
            infoWindowBuilder: "@vich_geographical.info_window_builder"
```

Comment: I am getting an exception : [2/2] Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: Missing argument 2 for ....allShopsMap::__construct(),

Comment: meze: do you think there's a workaround in your code to hide the last opened infoWindow? What happens is that every infoWindow you click remains open.

Comment: @RobertoDelgazzo, no. Don't think it's possible with google api